# I deleted songs right off my iPod, why are they again in my iPod after syncing?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, ipod-touch, music

I have 887 songs in my iTunes library, and last night I deleted some of them right off my iPod touch, 4th generation. At the end I got 769, and in the morning I connected my iPod to iTunes, I did some changes that had nothing to do with my music, because they were fine, but then I clicked sync and again, the songs I deleted from my Ipod were again in my iPod! how do I sync my iPod to actually "update" my iTunes library, I don't want to delete the music again or do I need to delete the same songs from my iTunes library too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell iTunes not to sync those songs.

1. Uncheck the songs you do not want to sync in the iTunes "Music" list.
2. Check "Sync only checked songs and Videos" in the options for the device.

[image: item checkbox]

Comment: "sync only checked songs and videos" is grayed out for me.